# I want to create a 2d static array with a special property where each element will be a hash map of a pair of elements?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

Can anyone suggest me the name to search for or topics of particular codes to study as I am a newbie in advanced java. I want to create a 2d static ARRAY where each element will not be only one element but it will be a chain of unknown number of elements which will be in pair and the chain may be later be used for sorting among itself. 
for eg: a[2][2] is the static 2d array;
where

```
a[0][0]= { (1,2), (2,3), (4,3), (4,5), (3,1)};
a[0][1]= {(2,4), (1,1), (5,6)};
a[1][0]= {(2,6), (6,4)};
a[1][1]={(1,3), (6,4), (2,1), (4,2)};
```

Comment: In other words, you need a 2D array with a random number of the outer array size and random items in the inner one?

Comment: not exactly, I need to do a 3d like graph where the elements will be a pair. eg. if there are parallel paths between vertices u,v with a pair of cost values as weight. then how to represent in matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following.

```
 ArrayList<int[]>[][] name = new ArrayList[5][5];
```

So you have a matrix of list, which can have any any length.
Each of those list contains an array of integers.

Here are some examples to fill and extract numbers from the object:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // this is for the compiler warning.
ArrayList<int[]>[][] matrix = new ArrayList[2][2];


int[] a = {1, 2};
int[] b = {3, 4};

// you will need serialise all the lists inside the ArraylistMatrix
matrix[0][0] = new ArrayList<>();
matrix[0][1] = new ArrayList<>();

matrix[0][0].add(a);
matrix[0][0].add(b); // matrix[0][0]= {(1,2), (3,4)}
matrix[0][1].add(a); // matrix[0][1]= {(1,2)}

int c = matrix[0][0].get(1)[1]; //this is 4
```

Good luck

Comment: thank you so much. can you provide me a full code with proper input and output as I am a novice in java and want to explore more. I would be grateful.

Comment: @Nikolas Its a warning, it compiles just fine. But i am curious you have a better answer?